# I cant send an email on Shared Hosting via laravel smtp, is there a way around this?

Tags: php, laravel, email

I cant send an email on Shared Hosting via laravel smtp.
My Hosting 'A2 Hosting' has blocked all outgoing smtp as stated on their [website](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/getting-started-guide/setting-up-e-mail/using-external-smtp-servers-to-send-e-mail)
Can someone maybe tell me what the best sollution for this problem is or if there
is a way around it?

The error:

> Swift_TransportException Connection could not be established with host
>   smtp.mailtrap.io [Connection refused #111]

Answer (score 1):

Use http based mailing services like:

- Mailgun
- SparkPost
- Postmark

Laravel also natively supported them: [source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mail#driver-prerequisites)